# Creating Website - Full Control

Tags: html, css, web

What is the best/most common way to create a website for a business? I would like to do the programming my self, and I don't want to do something like wordpress given the lack of full control. I've tried googling answers to this but all I find is sites recommending Wix or Wordpress. I've used Visual Studio in the past for ASP.NET, but I'd like to hear from someone with more knowledge.
My goal is to make a site would involve users being able to sign up and post results they have found, and although it sounds like something a cookie cuter forum model could handle there are some features that I don't see being able to handled by things like Wordpress or Wix.

Answer (score 1):

"there are some features that I don't see being able to handled by things like Wordpress "

Not sure where you got this information from, but with a wordpress.org site, you can add or delete anything you want from a wordpress theme. All you need to do is create a child theme based on the parent theme you select and you can edit the child theme to your liking.

For more info, check this out [creatingchildthemes](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2016/01/create-customize-wordpress-child-theme/)

If you haven't installed WordPress yet, I made an easy tutorial [marvelmoe.com/wordpress](http://marvelmoe.com/wordpress/)

Answer (score 0):

One way you can do this is to make it on GitHub, by creating a repository and coding it there. Then,you can get a custom URL from GoDaddy. Then you will have a site. This is what I did to make my site, and it worked perfectly.